# Can I use Wildfly 14 with Eclipse Oxygen.3a

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, eclipse-jee

Could someone please tell me how to get the option of using wildfly 14 with eclipse oxygen?  When I go to create a new server, it stops at wildfly 12 (fyi, I have installed wildfly 14).

Answer (score 1):

Jboss Tools is the pluging that it's used for creating a new server. If you update it to the last version you will see that you can create a WildFly 14 server (Tested in eclipse Photon).
Anyway, you can still create a WildFly 12 server, and choose a WildFly 14 directory, it should work without too much trouble.

Edit: According to Jboss Tools [documentation](https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.9.0.Final.html), the Wildfly 14 Server Adapter have been added in version 4.9.0 that requires eclipse photon.
In practice, I have 4.6.0 version installed, and I'm able to choose WildFly 14 server. Anyway, version 4.6.0 also requires eclipse photon. [Doc](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/photon/4.6.0.Final.html).

[image: jboss tools version]
[image: wildfly 14 connector]

Hope it helps!